# How to know which tab is currently selected on my Android app, using Calabash?

Tags: android, calabash

Our app uses tabs (`android.widget.TabWidget`).

It looks similar to

[image: example].

Using Calabash, how to verify that 'TAB1' is selected in example?

Comment: What is tab widget?

Comment: We really need a lot more information before we can answer this question. Please edit to give more information.

Comment: Agree with Kate, let's put this on hold until Qiang Ruan is able to clarify the question.

Comment: I  clarified for it so please open it.

Comment: Have you seen: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337514/android-tabwidget-detect-click-on-current-tab or https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/blob/master/ruby-gem/test-server/instrumentation-backend/src/sh/calaba/instrumentationbackend/actions/view/SelectTab.java.

Comment: I need a query. I referenced here already http://grokbase.com/t/gg/calabash-android/136vwrz3qn/how-to-know-which-tab-is-currently-selected but not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
query "TabView {:isSelected == true}"
```

Or to get only caption of active tab:

```
query("TabView {:isSelected == true}", "text").first
```

---

Another possible solution:

```
query("tabWidget", :context, :tabHost, :currentTab)
```

---

**And another one. This should work for you:**

`query "TabItemView {isSelected == true} TextView"`

***or text only:*** `query "TabItemView {isSelected == true} TextView", :text`

Comment: Sorry. Seem the query still not get the selected tab. Is there different solution?

Comment: I've updated an answer.

Comment: Sorry for disturbing you one more time. When I query with query("tabWidget", :currentTab) I got the error "No accessor for currentTab". Is this because the developer? https://www.dropbox.com/s/9epapxvl82lgaqv/Screenshot%202014-06-16%2015.44.42.png

Comment: Added one more solution. This should work for your app: `query "TabItemView {isSelected == true} TextView"`